# Firefox's sub menus disappears after the screen saver is active

Tags: firefox, menu

My Ubuntu's Firefox browser's sub menus disappears after the screen saver is active.
When I click on a menu topic like 'File' the sub menu appears, but when I move the mouse to select a menu item, the sub menu disappears.
I tried to disable the display hardware acceleration property, but it did not help.

Comment: By the way, this happens on all the computers running Ubuntu 11.04 I've tried (about 6).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this happens (it happens to me too), but if you minimize Firefox and then maximize it again, the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with X11

Did you tried to replace compiz?

`compiz --replace`

Comment: that would be 'nice' (_sic_) advise if his graphics card doesn't support compiz in the first place :) now that is inceasingly unlikely nowadays, BUT we are talking about a user who is experiencing display trouble to begin with!